# Cannot automatically start workflow for users outside of the active directory

Tags: 2010, workflow, designer-workflow, active-directory, impersonation

I have a web part that is a form that links to a list that anyone who comes to the public site (i.e. people who are not in the active directory) can fill out. I have a workflow (created in SharePoint designer 2010) that is suppose to trigger (which will send me an email) when a person fills out the form, but the workflow never executes automatically even though it's set to.

I've noticed that the resulting list items that are created have the system account as the creator of the list item. I have read that the system account cannot trigger workflows automatically.
I've tried the workflow impersonation step, but with no success.

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour. You can change it using following command

```
stsadm.exe –o setproperty –propertyname declarativeworkflowautostartonemailenabled –propertyvalue yes
```

Comment: if this is the default behavior of sharepoint, then does that mean sharepoint was not meant to be used in the way I am using it?